# For $n\ge4$ If every vertex has an even degree, then at least 3 vertices have the same degree.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Let $G$ be a simple undirected graph (no loops nor multi edges), $n=|v|$

My try:

Let $A,B,C,D$ be my vertices with no edges between them, their $deg.=0$ so the condition holds.

I can assign only $\large\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$ distinct $degrees$ because every $v$ has an $even\space degree$.

But how to show that at least $3 \space vertices $ have same $degree ?$ (I can draw it by adding edge after edge to my nodes but it doesn't give me any new clues)

Comment: How many distinct degrees are possible, already?

Comment: @Did sorry , I don't quite understand you.

Comment: Are you asking how to prove the assertion of your first sentence?

Comment: @kimchilover need to prove the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are $2n$ vertices, then the possible degrees are $2, 4, \ldots 2n - 2$, i.e. we have $n - 1$ unique possible degrees. We have to spread $n-1$ unique degrees among $2n$, so it is clear that at least 3 vertices should have same degree by pigeonhole principle.

If there are $2n + 1$ vertices, then the possible degrees are $2, 4, \ldots, 2n$, i.e. $n$ unique possible degrees. WE have to spread $n$ unique degrees among $2n + 1$ verticies, so it is clear even in this case that at least 3 vertices should have same degree by pigeonhole principle.

EDIT: The OP asked why I am not considering vertices of degree 0. This was an oversight. It can be fixed in this way. If there are three or more vertices of degree 0, we are done. By the above argument we are also done when there are no vertices of degree 0.

So all we have left are the cases of 1 or 2 vertices of degree 0.

Case 1 (two vertices of degree 0):

Case 1a) 2n vertices. Degree of 2n-2 is not possible because there are two vertices of degree 0. Same pigeonhole principle applies.

Case 1b) 2n+1 vertices. Degree of 2n is not possible because there are two 
vertices of degree 0. Sample pigeonhole principle applies.

Case 2 (one vertex of degree 0):

Case 2a) 2n vertices. One vertex has degree 0. So we have 2n-1 vertices left and degrees of 2, 4, ... 2n-2 to spread. Thus we have n-1 unique degrees to spread amongst 2n-1 vertices. pigeonhole principle...

Case 2b) 2n+1 vertices. One vertex has degree 0. So we have 2n vertices left and degrees of 2, 4, ... 2n-2 to spread. pigeonhole principle again...

Comment: why did you not count the 0 as a valid degree? if that is explained I will gladly mark it as an answer

Comment: I think I have fixed the problem now. Thanks for catching this, it was an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw all the graphs with 4 vertices such every vertex has degree even then you see it is true. Now with induction suppose the problem is true for all graphs with at most $K$ vertices. Suppose $G$ is a graph with $K+1$ vertices such every vertex has degree even. If a vertex in $G$( for example $v$) has degree $0$ then suppose the graph $G-v$ and with induction it has three vertices of same degree. Suppose no vertex of $G$ has degree zero. We have two condition:
If the number of vertices of $G$ is $2p+1$ then the degrees come from ${2,\cdots ,2p}$ now with Pigeonhole principle at least three of them have same degree. 
If the number of vertices of $G$ is $2p$ then the degrees come from ${2,\cdots ,2p-2}$ and again use Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Because when we remove the vertex of degree $0$ in graph $G$ then we get a graph which all vertices has degree even again and order(number of vertices) of new graph is less than $G$. Now we can use of induction.

Comment: let #vertices = $2p$ so we have a total of $p-1$ unique assignable vertices.
from pigeonhole : we must put $2p$ pigeons in $p-1$ holes so after the formula $2p=k*(p-1)+1,k=\lfloor\frac{2p-1}{p-1}\rfloor$ so I can say $k = 2$ ?

Comment: Why you put $2p=k\ast (p-1)+1$?
Just consider that $\lfloor\frac{2p-1}{p-1} \rfloor \geq 3$

Comment: See that here $2p \geq 3\ast (p-1)+1$ so we can use pigeonhole theorem as it is represented in Wikipedia.

Comment: I still don't understand why you removed the 0 degree , because if you add it back then that means that we'll have only $p$ unique degrees and this won't hold anymore $2p\ge3*p+1$